# Questions about OAEP for RSA

Tags: rsa, padding, oaep

I have two questions about OAEP for RSA.

1. How are the number of bits to pad with 0 chosen? For example, if I'm sending a 255 byte message with RSA-2048 I have 8 unused bits (1 byte). Should I split the remainder bits evenly so I pad with 4 zeroes and my $r$ is 4 random bits, or do I pick the number of bits to pad randomly?
2. Does it matter if the hash functions $G$ and $H$ are the same (e.g. if both are SHA-256)?

Variables are in reference to the ones in the diagram found in the Wikipedia article “[Optimal asymmetric encryption padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding)”.

**Bonus question:** What's the proper technique for expanding and shrinking data using hash functions? Could I use the hash as a seed for a secure PRNG and then generate $n$ random bits, or is that wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First off, the maximum size of a message you can use is determined by the desired length of the padding (in my case, I am using RSA-2048 so I wanted a final padded length of 256 bytes) and the hash function you are using.

   The formula is `messageLength = desiredLength - 2 * hashOutputSize - 1` (in my case, I wanted to use SHA-256 so `hashOutputSize` would be 32 bytes).

   The number of zeroes padded is `desiredLength - messageLength - 2 * hashOutputSize - 1`. This can be 0 sometimes. There are not always padded zeroes…!

   After reading “[PKCS #1: RSA Cryptography Specifications Version 2.0](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2437.txt)”, I realize that this question isn't important/doesn't make a lot of sense.
2. Yes. The specification only calls for 1 hash function as a parameter, not two different ones.
3. **Bonus Question**

   MGF1 is what I used for generating masks (i.e. "expanding and shrinking data using hash functions").

   And if anyone is reading this in the future and needs more resources to understand OAEP, I translated it to Java code (this is OAEP, not RSA-OAEP). Also, not strictly related to the forum, but if you can program this might make things easier to follow along:

   ```
   public class OAEP {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           byte[] myMessage = "I wonder if this will work".getBytes("UTF-8");
           byte[] padded = pad(myMessage, "SHA-256 MGF1", myMessage.length + 32 + 32 + 1);
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           for (byte b : padded) {
               sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
           }
           System.out.println(sb.toString());
           byte[] unpadded = unpad(padded, "SHA-256 MGF1");
           System.out.println(new String(unpadded, "UTF-8"));
       }
       public static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(); // Uhh you may want to replace this though
       public static byte[] SHA256(byte[] input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
           MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
           return digest.digest(input);
       }
       public static byte[] MGF1(byte[] seed, int seedOffset, int seedLength, int desiredLength) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
           int hLen = 32;
           int offset = 0;
           int i = 0;
           byte[] mask = new byte[desiredLength];
           byte[] temp = new byte[seedLength + 4];
           System.arraycopy(seed, seedOffset, temp, 4, seedLength);
           while (offset < desiredLength) {
               temp[0] = (byte) (i >>> 24);
               temp[1] = (byte) (i >>> 16);
               temp[2] = (byte) (i >>> 8);
               temp[3] = (byte) i;
               int remaining = desiredLength - offset;
               System.arraycopy(SHA256(temp), 0, mask, offset, remaining < hLen ? remaining : hLen);
               offset = offset + hLen;
               i = i + 1;
           }
           return mask;
       }
       public static byte[] unpad(byte[] message, String params) throws Exception {
           String[] tokens = params.split(" ");
           if (tokens.length != 2 || !tokens[0].equals("SHA-256") || !tokens[1].equals("MGF1")) {
               return null;
           }
           int mLen = message.length;
           int hLen = 32;
           if (mLen < (hLen << 1) + 1) {
               return null;
           }
           byte[] copy = new byte[mLen];
           System.arraycopy(message, 0, copy, 0, mLen);
           byte[] seedMask = MGF1(copy, hLen, mLen - hLen, hLen);
           for (int i = 0; i < hLen; i++) {
               copy[i] ^= seedMask[i];
           }
           byte[] paramsHash = SHA256(params.getBytes("UTF-8"));
           byte[] dataBlockMask = MGF1(copy, 0, hLen, mLen - hLen);
           int index = -1;
           for (int i = hLen; i < mLen; i++) {
               copy[i] ^= dataBlockMask[i - hLen];
               if (i < (hLen << 1)) {
                   if (copy[i] != paramsHash[i - hLen]) {
                       return null;
                   }
               } else if (index == -1) {
                   if (copy[i] == 1) {
                       index = i + 1;
                   }
               }
           }
           if (index == -1 || index == mLen) {
               return null;
           }
           byte[] unpadded = new byte[mLen - index];
           System.arraycopy(copy, index, unpadded, 0, mLen - index);
           return unpadded;
       }
       public static byte[] pad(byte[] message, String params, int length) throws Exception {
           String[] tokens = params.split(" ");
           if (tokens.length != 2 || !tokens[0].equals("SHA-256") || !tokens[1].equals("MGF1")) {
               return null;
           }
           int mLen = message.length;
           int hLen = 32;
           if (mLen > length - (hLen << 1) - 1) {
               return null;
           }
           int zeroPad = length - mLen - (hLen << 1) - 1;
           byte[] dataBlock = new byte[length - hLen];
           System.arraycopy(SHA256(params.getBytes("UTF-8")), 0, dataBlock, 0, hLen);
           System.arraycopy(message, 0, dataBlock, hLen + zeroPad + 1, mLen);
           dataBlock[hLen + zeroPad] = 1;
           byte[] seed = new byte[hLen];
           random.nextBytes(seed);
           byte[] dataBlockMask = MGF1(seed, 0, hLen, length - hLen);
           for (int i = 0; i < length - hLen; i++) {
               dataBlock[i] ^= dataBlockMask[i];
           }
           byte[] seedMask = MGF1(dataBlock, 0, length - hLen, hLen);
           for (int i = 0; i < hLen; i++) {
               seed[i] ^= seedMask[i];
           }
           byte[] padded = new byte[length];
           System.arraycopy(seed, 0, padded, 0, hLen);
           System.arraycopy(dataBlock, 0, padded, hLen, length - hLen);
           return padded;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Just as a note, you can use one hash function as two using domain separation. So, if h() is a good hash function You can use G(x)=h(0||x) and H(x)=h(1||x) as independent hashes